# How will the new development of Java influence its interoperability with languages like Scala and Clojure?

Tags: java, scala, clojure

As far as I understand, both Scala and Clojure have been designed as new languages that

1. depend on the JVM, and
2. easily integrate with Java code, in the sense that they allow to use Java classes inside Scala and Clojure code.

Starting with Java 8 (and maybe even more strongly with subsequent versions of Java), there will be changes in the semantics of the Java language.

I wanted to ask how these changes will impact the interoperability between Java and Scala / Clojure and what the consequences will be. For example, since lambdas in Java 8 are not objects (see e.g. [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-August/003877.html)), Scala and Clojure might have to deal with Java values that are not objects. Would this be a problem?

I can think of the following scenarios:

1. The Scala or Clojure language will be extended to adapt to the new Java semantics (to handle the new non-object values) and support interoperability with Java.
2. The Scala or Clojure language will **not** be extended. This would only be possible if the new Java features like function values can be mapped to existing concepts. E.g., in Scala even a function is an object, so I guess Java functions would again be wrapped into some kind of objects when they become visible to Scala.
3. The Scala or Clojure language will continue to support interoperability up to Java 6 or 7, without following latest Java's development. This would require that older versions of Java be still supported (at least by OpenJDK or another project), so that these languages can be based on a more conservative / stable branch of Java.

Summarizing: can we expect that the future development of Java will have an impact on languages like Scala and Clojure to maintain interoperability with Java? Is there some (link to) ongoing discussion on this topic already?

**Note**

I can imagine that Scala, Clojure, and other JVM-based languages won't have any major problems updating their implementation to newer versions of the JVM (and that new JVM features will make this implementation even easier). My question focuses on features of Java as a language and whether / how other JVM-language will be able to "see" / use these new features, not on whether JVM-based languages will run on the latest JVM's.

Comment: It is imprecise to say that Scala etc. depend on Java. They depend on JVM byte code. All the interoperability features deal with bytecode, not Java language source code, so whatever changes are made to Java itself are no threat. Only changes made to the JVM could affect these languages, and the JVM is extremely conservative - it basically never removes support for anything. In fact, most changes in the JVM nowadays are intended specifically *for* the newer dynamic languages.

Comment: @Kilian Foth: As far as I know a Scala `String` is a Java `String`. So Scala uses certain Java library classes. But I can change the formulation if you think it is too strong.

Comment: @Kilian Foth: I have removed the term __depend__ because the focus of my question is rather on interoperability between Scala and Java resp. Clojure and Java.

Comment: @KilianFoth This should be an answer because it addresses the major concern of the question.  The number one goal of any new Java release is backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Giorgio Are you sure that Scala String is simply the Java API String class? I understood the Scala string to be considered its own language construct that compiles to a String like object in byte code, but then I may be wrong. Even so future Java releases cannot fundamentally alter the behavior of String due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: @maple_shaft: I have corrected my question and removed the word "depend". As I have pointed out in another comment, my issue is not how Scala or Clojure depend on Java or JVM features, but how Scala / Clojure can "see" Java features. As far as I know they can see Java 6 features like classes, interfaces, objects, methods, primitive data types. This allows Scala / Clojure to use (call) Java 6 code. My question is, will these languages also "see" (and, therefore, be able to use) future Java language constructs or would this require extensions to the Scala / Clojure languages?

Comment: "Are you sure that Scala String is simply the Java API String class?": Not 100% sure. The point is that in Scala (and, AFAIK, in Clojure) you can take a Java class and use it as it is.

Comment: See also http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4. "Scala classes are Java classes, and vice versa. You can call the methods of either language from methods in the other one." This is the current state, it is not clear to me if things will remain the same, e.g. if Java is going to have data values that are not object.

Comment: @maple_shaft Yes, a Scala String is a Java String. As with any other class, the mechanism of implicits can be used to add new methods to the existing class at compile time, but these are translated by the compiler in calls to methohds on a wrapper class.

Comment: What are you using "resp." to mean?

Comment: @Mike Partridge: I have removed "resp.". I hope the text is clearer now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually Java 8 doesn't introduce much that will be detrimental to other JVM languages that interop with Java. The work done on Lambdas helped fix a number of small issues around invokedynamic, MethodHandles , MethodReferences etc - but apart from that it's carry on as normal.  That said, there's a whole new bunch of APIs that the other JVM languages could potentially call into now.  Which ones they'll use by default or not is up to them.

The largest change impacting interop actually came in with Java 7 - with the  invokedynamic bytecode that allows dynamic/late binding calls within the JVM - something that was initially designed for the other languages on the JVM.  It's since been very usefully adapted for Lamdbas, so as of Java 8, Java will actually start emitting these bytecodes.

Some languages (JRuby for example) are already heavily using invokedynamic, whilst others (Scala, Groovy et al) are still investigating its use or are in the early stages of patching it in.  In theory it makes their dynamic calls almost as performant as existing Java invokestatic calls, as opposed to the myriad of slower workarounds they were forced to use in the past.

Java 9 will bring more challenges for JVM languages with project Jigsaw coming into the platform which will be the beginning of the end for traditionally class loading and classpaths for the JVM.  The JVM language folks are pretty aware of this and I expect some sensible collaboration to take place.

Comment: One point that is not clear to me it the following. Say that a Scala object invokes a method of a Java object implemented in Java 7. The result of the method will be an object (or void) and Scala knows how to handle Java objects. In Java 8 the result of a method invocation could be a lambda, which is not an object. How will Scala handle this new non-object value?

Comment: I imagine it will map to Scala's equivalent Closure. Since Scala arguably has a superset over Java 8 in terms of its Closures support that should be possible (although there will be substantial devil in the detail).

Comment: But, as far as I know, a Scala closure is an object.

Comment: Groovy already support invoke dynamic.  They just don't want to deprecate their non-invoke-dynamic support because they want to be able to run on Java 1.6.  Scala have it on their schedule for the 2.11 release to start using invoke dynamic.

Comment: Yep. Scala only just recently dropped support for Java 1.5, it'll be a *long* time till they drop 1.6.

Comment: JVM compatibility is an important issue but I am more interested in language compatibility / incompatibilities. As far as I know, classes, interfaces, methods, primitive types from Java 6 can be "seen" by Scala (and Closure ?) directly. What about the new Java features?

Comment: @Giorgio The language features of Java are inconsequential as most of those equate to bytecode tricks when compiled anyway. If we accept that the JVM will always be backwards compatible, even if new bytecodes are introduced, then Scala will be unaffected and can choose to take advantage of those new JVM features at their convenience.

Comment: @maple_shaft: So you mean there will be no problem like calling a Java 8 class / method that uses some Java 8 features and getting back a result that Scala / Clojure cannot understand?

Comment: "The language features of Java are inconsequential as most of those equate to bytecode tricks when compiled anyway.": If another language wants to use a Java construct, it must be able to recognize the bytecode generated for that construct. If Java introduces a new constructs that maps to new bytecode, the host language should at least implement a new wrapper / interface to recognize and use the new bytecode. E.g. if a Java 8 lambda did not create an object but some new construct with new, specific bytecode for it, the host language must be adapted to recognize it.

Comment: @Giorgio: "If Java introduces a new constructs that maps to new bytecode" – Java *cannot* introduce new constructs that map to new bytecode because the bytecode isn't controlled by the Java Language Specification, it is controlled by the Java Virtual Machine Specification, which is a totally separate thing.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: I would not be surprised if the JVM specification was extended to support new Java features. After all, Java is the primary language for which the JVM exists at all. While other languages can decide not to use new JVM features for their own implementation, they would be forced to use them in order to access new Java code.

Comment: But from the whole discussion my doubts seem to be ruled out. Even though there are some statement like "lambdas are not objects" (http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-August/003877.html), they are indeed mapped to objects in the compiled code and so other languages like Scala, Clojure, etc, can still look at that bytecode and treat them as objects. At least, this is what I have understood.

Comment: @Giorgio: Sure, but no such changes are planned for the Java 8 platform. In fact, the JVMS was only extended *twice* in the entire history of the Java Platform, in 2003 and 2010, and the second time (introduction of the `invokedynamic` bytecode) was specifically to support languages *other* than Java; in fact, the Java 7 language *does not* support or use that bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Scala's about to be left behind when Java adds lambdas because Java lambdas get assigned a type according to the context they're used in, whereas Scala lambdas get assigned a type based on their arities, parameter types and return types, so e.g.,

```
executor.execute(() -> { System.out.println("hello world"); });
```

from Java 8 can be written in Scala as:

```
executor execute new Runnable {
    override def run() { println("hello world") }
}
```

unless you use/write some wrappers converting Scala's () => Unit to Runnable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also for addressing my question (+1). If I understand correctly, Scala will have to continue to use anonymous classes to instantiate interfaces in a context in which Java 8 will use lambdas (because Java 8 lambdas have a different semantics than Scala lambdas). Another point that is not clear to me is what will happen if a Java method returns a Java lambda. What happens if a Scala class calls that method? What will be the return type in Scala?

Comment: @Giorgio In Java 8 a lambda expression is a language-level shortcut to create an instance of interface that declares a single method and which is deferred by context. So when a Java 8 method returns a lambda, it actually returns an instance of interface which is declared as the method's return type. As of Scala 2.9.1, the return type is  going to be simply an instance of some interface say (Runnable or Comparator) which you can **not** treat as a Scala lambda, unless you or future releases of Scala libary introduce an implicit conversion from that interface to Scala lambda type.

Comment: @SkyDan: Ok, so Scala will see Java lambdas as objects implementing some interface. This point was not clear to me: I thought Java would generate some bytecode that was different from that of an object. But it must be an object under the hood, otherwise it would not be recognized as the implementation of an interface. I think I got it now.

Comment: @Giorgio, also if you want to know more about lambda-related changes in Java 8 and forces that drive these changes, I recommend you to read this [fascinating and detailed overview of the Lambda project](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html).

Comment: @SkyDan: Reading it now. It seems to me that lambdas **do** represent objects (even though the type / interface is inferred from the context in which they are defined). So the information given at http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-August/003877.html ("lambdas are not 
objects") is incorrect or, at least, misleading.

Comment: @Giorgio, He just speaks in favor of 'function types', however that's all there is to it. The current draft of the Lambda project clearly states that a lambda is an object, and I think they have already passed the point, when this statement could still be subject to a change.

Comment: So basically a lambda expression constructs an object for a given interface almost like an anonymous inner class would do (apart from the different handling of `this` and maybe other minor differences). It starts to make more sense.